# Callkit example or sample for Android platform along with agora.io calling service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, callkit, agora.io

and thank you in advance for helping, I am using agora.io calling service in many applications calling module the issues I currently facing is that I have never found any perfect sample for callkit that works perfectly with my calling service i.e agora.io.

Answer (score 1):

Agora.io has example for iOS Callkit [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/Calling-Interface/Agora-RTC-With-CallKit).

Unfortunately, I could not find one for Android.

Due to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/157363/158990), Android does have similar things like Callkit, but it's full of bugs, so no one wanna try it any more.

Comment: exactly I have discussed with Agora.io technical team that why not you guy creates an example of Callkit for Android as for IOS. they replied that for IOS it is essential but for android, it is not that's why.